# Applying a class from an array to a repeated item with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know I'm close here but it only adds a class from the colors array to the 1st 3 postbox divs:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

    var toCopy = $('.postbox');
    var colors = ['box1','box2','box3'];

    for (var i = 1;i < 7;i++) {
        $('.rightCol').append(toCopy.clone());
    }

    $('.postbox').each(function(i, val) {
        $(this).addClass(colors[i]);
    });

});
```

Here's the end result using the above:

```
<div class="rightCol">
    <div class="postbox box1"></div>
    <div class="postbox box2"></div>
    <div class="postbox box3"></div>
    <div class="postbox"></div>
    <div class="postbox"></div>
    <div class="postbox"></div>
    <div class="postbox"></div>
</div>
```

How do I get it to keep repeating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.postbox')` has 7 elements, and `colors` only has 3.  This is why only the 1st 3 have colors.

If you want the colors to cycle through the list, you'll have to use the [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), `%`.

```
$('.postbox').each(function(i, val) {
   $(this).addClass(colors[i % colors.length]);
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Rt6z6/

Comment: is there a way I can loop through those 3 and apply classes to the other 4?

Comment: @Rob: I edited my answer.  Using `i % colors.lenth` should do what you want.  It will cycle through the colors array as you loop through elements.

Comment: Hmmm doesn't seem to be working - I'll mess around with it for a bit

Comment: @Rob: I spelled `length` wrong >.<  It seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Rt6z6/

Comment: Haha yup - that'll do it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the `%` operator:

```
 $(this).addClass(colors[i%colors.length]);
```

Try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/xgnnc/

---

## The `%` operator

According to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp), the `%` operator means `Modulus`, which gives you the remainder of the division.

For example:

`3 % 2` will give you `1` because `2 x 1 +1 = 3`.

Hope it helps you out!

---

## Other Uses of `%`!

`%` is very useful in determining if a row is odd or even.
reference: http://snook.ca/archives/php/the_modulo_oper

```
(i % 2) ? /*Even*/ : /*Odd*/
```

Since `i % 2` will give you only 0 or 1.